# Query result is too large to exceed the memory limits in hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I use `SELECT` to query a result but it is too large to cause the memory limit out.

```
SELECT
    t.requestid,
    t.bucket
FROM
    (SELECT
         requestid,
         IF (strategy_path LIKE '%4-54-%', 'EXP', 'BASE') AS bucket
     FROM
         log.aar
     WHERE
         dt BETWEEN '20210908' AND '20210917'
         AND channel = 'S'
         AND slot_ids LIKE '%50011%'
         AND (strategy_path LIKE '%4-5-1%'
              OR strategy_path LIKE '%4-5-2%')
         AND platform = 'AT') t
GROUP BY
    1, 2
```

So if there is a way to optimize memory usage without setting a larger memory limit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried paging?

Comment: 1. Why group by? You can distinct instead ? (Not sure of it will improve perf) 2. Strategy path filter seems duplicated. 3. Try to see if you have partition on some columns - if yes you must use it in filter. 4. Compute stats on the table 5. Run explain to check where memory is getting consumed. 6. Run the qry, see the process pregress in url and analyze to see when and where its crossing mem limit.

Comment: I'm not sure how this engine handles derived tables, but your SQL does not require a derived table: `SELECT DISTINCT col1, expression AS col2 FROM log.aar WHERE ...;` without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @KoushikRoy 1. Agree with it. 2. It is a mispelling and I have corrected it. 3. This is a log hive table that seems partition on `dt` column. 4. What kind of stats that I should compute like statistics of columns or something else. 5 and 6. I will try this later to analyze it.

Comment: please show the full exception message. Result has nothing to do with memory because result is not in memory. Even more: each reducer stores its results separately. It is not cleas which container fails, so show the exception and much better the part of execution log where we can see how many containers are running on each vertex (is it Tez or MR?) and which are failing